# Scikit learn SVC predict probability doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svc

I built sentiment analyzer using SVM classifier. I trained model with probability=True and it can give me probability. But when I pickled my model and load it again later, the probability doesn't work anymore.

The model:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC
pipeline_svm = Pipeline([
    ('bow', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('classifier', SVC(probability=True)),])

# pipeline parameters to automatically explore and tune
param_svm = [
  {'classifier__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'classifier__kernel': ['linear']},
  {'classifier__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'classifier__gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'classifier__kernel': ['rbf']},
]

grid_svm = GridSearchCV(
    pipeline_svm,
    param_grid=param_svm,
    refit=True,
    n_jobs=-1, 
    scoring='accuracy',
    cv=StratifiedKFold(label_train, n_folds=5),)

svm_detector_reloaded = cPickle.load(open('svm_sentiment_analyzer.pkl', 'rb'))
print(svm_detector_reloaded.predict([""""Today is awesome day"""])[0])
```

Gives me:

> AttributeError: predict_proba is not available when  probability=False

Comment: Can you show the code where you originally save the object to `''svm_sentiment_analyzer.pkl''?`

Comment: did you try to call `predict_proba` rather than `predict` when getting that `AttributeError`? Otherwise this is a bit puzzling

Answer (score 20):

Use: `SVM(probability=True)`

or

```
grid_svm = GridSearchCV(
    probability=True
    pipeline_svm,
    param_grid=param_svm,
    refit=True,
    n_jobs=-1, 
    scoring='accuracy',
    cv=StratifiedKFold(label_train, n_folds=5),)
```

Answer (score 8):

Adding (probability=True) while initializing the classifier as someone above suggested, resolved my error:

```
clf = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1e9, gamma=1e-07, probability=True).fit(xtrain,ytrain)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CallibratedClassifierCV for probability score output.

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV

model_svc = LinearSVC()
model = CalibratedClassifierCV(model_svc) 
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Save model using pickle.

```
import pickle
filename = 'linearSVC.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

Load model using pickle.load.

`model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))`

Now start prediction.

```
pred_class = model.predict(pred)
probability = model.predict_proba(pred)
```

Answer (score 1):

If that can help, pickling the model with with:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(grid_svm, open('svm_sentiment_analyzer.pkl', 'wb'))
```

and loading the model and predicting with

```
svm_detector_reloaded = pickle.load(open('svm_sentiment_analyzer.pkl', 'rb'))
print(svm_detector_reloaded.predict_proba(["Today is an awesome day"])[0])
```

returned me two probabilities fine, after working on your code to rerun it and training the model on a pandas `sents` DataFrame with

```
grid_svm.fit(sents.Sentence.values, sents.Positive.values)
```

Best practices (e.g. using `joblib`) on model serialization can be found at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the predprobs function to calculate the scores or probabilities/scores as asked in the auc(y_true, **y_score**), the issue is because of y_score.
you can convert it as shown in the following line of code

```
# Classifier - Algorithm - SVM
# fit the training dataset on the classifier
SVM = svm.SVC(C=1.0, kernel='linear', degree=3, gamma='auto',probability=True)
SVM.fit(Train_X_Tfidf,Train_Y)
# predict the labels on validation dataset
predictions_SVM = SVM.predict(Test_X_Tfidf)
# Use accuracy_score function to get the accuracy
**print("SVM Accuracy Score -> ",accuracy_score(predictions_SVM, Test_Y))**

probs = SVM.**predict_proba**(Test_X_Tfidf)
preds = probs[:,1]
fpr, tpr, threshold = **roc_curve(Test_Y, preds)**
**print("SVM Area under curve -> ",auc(fpr, tpr))**
```

see the difference between the accuracy_score and the auc(), you need the scores of predictions.